# Get percentages of age distribution by field using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[10,11,10,20,25,10],'field':['cat','cat','cat','dog','cow','cat']})
>>> df
   age field
0   10   cat
1   11   cat
2   10   cat
3   20   dog
4   25   cow
5   10   cat
```

My goal is to `groupby('field')`, use it as index and have age columns from `1` to `90` and get percentage distribution for each field, like this:

```
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   10  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19   20 21 22 23 24   25 ...
field                                                                                 
cat    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  75  25  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0    0 ...
dog    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  100  0  0  0  0    0 ...
cow    0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    0  0  0  0  0  100 ...
```

Please help me... thanks for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is `pivot_table`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[10,11,10,20,25,10],'field':['cat','cat','cat','dog','cow','cat']})

pivot = \
(df
 .assign(vals=1)
 .pivot_table(values='vals', index='field', columns='age', aggfunc='sum')
 .fillna(0)
)

row_totals = pivot.sum(axis=1)

percentages = pivot.div(row_totals, axis=0) * 100

final = percentages.reindex(range(1,91), axis=1, fill_value=0.0)
```

1. `pivot_table` calculates frequencies of occurences for crossess between `age` and `field`
2. `row_totals` calculate occurrencies in rows, which in turn are used to caluclate percentages in rows `percentages`
3. finally, we need to add empty columns 1-90

```
age     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9     10  ...   81   82   83  \
field                                                     ...                  
cat    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  75.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
cow    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   
dog    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  ...  0.0  0.0  0.0   

age     84   85   86   87   88   89   90  
field                                     
cat    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
cow    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
dog    0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: "a" should be "pivot" instead

Comment: I found out that you can also do the following: pivot = pd.crosstab(adults_full.field, adults_full.age)